# Pretty Basic question but why do you need brackets after defining a function?

Tags: javascript

`function exampleFunction() {}`

Why do you need the **()** after defining **exampleFunction**??

Comment: this is called a syntactic rule. all languages have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets at the end of a function can be used to define parameters when calling it.

For example:

```js
alertSentence("Hello, this is an example!");

function alertSentence(string) {
    alert(string);
}
```

This would show an alert dialog with the string: "Hello, this is an example!"

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a language that was defined following the patterns of c. Wikipedia says it's part of the simula programming language family [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages). Languages in this family define function parameters using parentheses. Other language families have other ways (see python for an example). Ultimately it's a bit of arbitrary syntax that allows programmers to explicitly define what they want the computer to do and a way for the computer to understand them.